# Bind event to dynamically created HTML elements with vanilla JavaScript [no jquery]

Tags: javascript, html, events, event-handling, pjax

I need to attach an event to a dynamically created element. With jQuery I can archive this by using the following code:

```
$("body").on("click", ".my-element", function() {});
```

And if I added a new `.my-element`, it automatically got the event attached.

I'm not creating the elements via `document.createElement("div");`, but I'm using [pjax](https://github.com/MoOx/pjax) to reload just some parts of the page, so the main JavaScript file just loads one time, for that reason events need to be attached dynamically.

How can I achieve that with vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: Unmark as duplicated please. The answer you posted is made with jquery.

Comment: You might find this useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pure JavaScript version of your jQuery example

```
$("body").on("click", ".my-element", function() {});
```

would be:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target &&
        e.target.classList.contains("my-element")) {
        // handle event here
    }
});
```

See example below.

```js
const addTestElements = () => {
    var el = document.createElement("p"),
        node = document.createTextNode("Test element, class 'my-element'");

    el.classList.add("my-element");
    el.appendChild(node);
    document.body.appendChild(el);

    el = document.createElement("p");
    node = document.createTextNode("Test element, class 'test'");
    el.classList.add("test");
    el.appendChild(node);
    document.body.appendChild(el);
}

document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", addTestElements);

document.body.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target &&
        e.target.classList.contains("my-element")) {
        console.clear();
        console.log("An element with class 'my-element' was clicked.")
        e.target.style.fontWeight = e.target.style.fontWeight === "bold" ? "normal" : "bold";
    }
});
```

```html
<button id="add">Add element</button>
```

Comment: Mmm, I'll give it a try! But, attach a body event listener is a good idea? Or is my jquery code doing it now? xD

Comment: jQuery does the same thing under the hood: if the body is clicked, if check if it matches the selector (class "my-element" in this case) and executes the callback function when required.