# form submit event listener not working on pages with data-binding

Tags: javascript, dom, data-binding, knockout.js, event-listener

In my JavaScript code there is a form submit event listener added as follows:

```
form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener("submit", eventHandler, false);

function eventHandler(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("eventHandler is called!......");
}
```

This works well with most webpages (e.g. facebook, LinkedIn, etc.) However, it fails to capture the submit event on the pages with (I think) data-binding (e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/). The issue is that the event listener is not capturing the submit event on these pages  hence the event handler is never called.

The form element with data-binding looks like this:

```
<form name="f1" id="i0281" novalidate="novalidate" spellcheck="false" method="post" target="_top" autocomplete="off" data-bind="autoSubmit: forceSubmit, attr: { action: postUrl }, ariaHidden: activeDialog" action="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/login">
...
....
</form>
```

As I understand when you use the submit binding on a form, Knockout will prevent the browser’s default submit action for that form. My question is how can I listen to knockout submit events and trigger my custom event handler?

Thanks

Comment: Still looking for a solution to this submit event listener problem. I might be missing something obvious but any ideas will be really appreciated :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54057965/bind-event-to-dynamically-created-html-elements-with-vanilla-javascript-no-jque

Comment: Where did you find this `autoSubmit` Knockout binding? Are you confusing it with the `submit` binding? https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html

Comment: @awj - yes, I have seen the knockout documentation for submit binding. autoSubmit is used on this login page https://login.microsoftonline.com/

Comment: But perhaps `autoSubmit` is a custom binding developed by whoever built that page. Custom bindings - _i.e._, your own bindings - are quite easy to build. I can't find any documentation for `autoSubmit` which is why I think it's a custom binding, the code for which you probably don't have. Have you tried using the `submit` binding?

Comment: That was my suspicion too. I think it's fair to conclude that autoSubmit is a custom binding not Knockout binding.

Comment: I've found a solution to the problem by adding a click event listener to the input element of type submit. This allows calling the event handler even if a submit event is not created due to custom bindings.